Copy or move files using Finder, but from Terminal
To copy or move file to a different folder using Terminal, the obvious way is to use the cp and mv commands.
But for users who often put important information in the "Comments" section of the "Get Info" window of their files and folders, cp and mv have a drawback that comments are sometimes lost.
The only reliable way I have found so far to copy/move files using Terminal and preserve comments is to use AppleScript.
I have several snippets for that, but currently they work just to demonstrate the idea, and that is to say, they are not a script that you can use with arbitrary targets and destinations like cpx <target> <destination>. Here they are, just in case, and though I will be very appreciated for help to convert them into a script that will work like cpx <target> <destination>, this is not what my question is about.

Suppose you have
~/
|- dir1/
   |- dir2/
   |  |- dir3/
   |  |- file
   |
   |- dir4/
      |- dir5/

Then:
to copy the file to dir3, use:
osascript << SCRIPT
set currentFolder to "$(pwd)" as POSIX file as text
tell application "Finder"
  duplicate file (currentFolder & "file") to folder (currentFolder & "dir3:")
end tell
SCRIPT

to copy it to dir4, use either
osascript << SCRIPT
set currentFolder to "$(pwd)" as POSIX file as text
set parentFolder to "$(dirname $PWD)" as POSIX file as text
tell application "Finder"
  duplicate file (currentFolder & "file") to folder (parentFolder & "dir4:")
end tell
SCRIPT

or
osascript << SCRIPT
set currentFolder to "$(pwd)" as POSIX file as text
tell application "Finder"
  set parentFolder to (container of folder currentFolder) as text
  duplicate file (currentFolder & "file") to folder (parentFolder & "dir4:")
end tell
SCRIPT


And here is my question: Maybe I overcomplicate things and instead of using AppleScript, I can use something similar to open -a <app> <file>?
# this works. this is used to open a file using a specific app
open -a <yourapp> <yourfile>

# this doesn't work and just a demonstration of my idea
copy -a finder <target> <destination>


Did you look at man ditto? Not sure it copies Finder comments though.

@nohillside Yes, I tried. It doesn't make a difference, and that is to say, is not a replacement for Finder/AppleScript copying and moving.

Finder uses .DSStore and extended attributes to store its comments, but sucks at syncing the attribute back to the store, so you are pretty much stuck using it.  Note that osascript can pass arguments to a script's run handler.

@red_menace "Note that osascript can pass arguments to a script's run handler" Could you explain how it can be used?

A script that is to be used with osascript can include a run handler with a parameter, which will be a list of arguments passed to it by the command (see the man page for more information).  For example:
on run args
   try
      if args is not in {missing value, {}, me} then
         -- args will be a list, parse arguments as desired
         set source to first item of args as POSIX file as text -- Finder doesn't know POSIX
         set destination to second item of args as POSIX file as text
         tell application "Finder" to duplicate file source to folder destination
      end if
      return "done." -- don't need the text representation of the Finder reference
   on error errmess
      display alert "Script Error" message errmess
   end try
end run

In addition to text, the script can be saved to a file, placed in a bash/zsh wrapper/shortcut, etc.  It can then be called with osascript using the desired arguments - for example, the above script can be saved somewhere and called with:
osascript /path/to/script /source/file/path /destination/folder/path


Thank you very much! This is a great supplementary thing to know.
